# Is there any posibility to check if function has inside call of another function?

Tags: javascript

let say I have the function:

```
function function1(n) {
  function function2() {
    function function3() {
        function function4() {
            return n * 2;
        }
        return function4()
    }
    return function3()
  }
  return function2()
}
```

First thing is, if I have option in JS to check if I have call a function inside function1? For example I have this function in other JS file and I don't know what is inside of it and I only know name of Funtion1.

Second thing if first is impossible, how to check if I exactly know name of function inside Funtion1 (for example I know that inside should be function2), is there possibility to check only if I have this function inside or not?

I'm just starting my adventure with JS, so please be understanding and patient :)

Comment: Why do you need to know this? This seems to be a strange thing to need to know even as a JavaScript expert. What bigger problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function1.toString()` will give you the full text of the function (not the result of its execution) so starting from there you could look for ways to call a function (e.g. something before parentheses)

An uncurated example:

```js
function function1(n) {
  function function2() {
    function function3() {
        function function4() {
            return n * 2;
        }
        return function4()
    }
    return function3()
  }
  return function2()
}

const regex = /.*\(\)/g
const result = function1.toString().match(regex).filter(x => x.search(/function /) < 0)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. I have to read more about regExp and filtering to analyze your idea, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It’s unclear what you want to do with this functionality, so this may be an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

But, you could technically use the *deprecated* [Function.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) property to check which function called the currently running function; Possibly in conjunction with the well supported [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property to get the name of the caller function.